# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermer How can i fix this problem with my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am getting this error in my code TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes
I have a voximplant.ts in my utils folder in which i have that some and i am calling that initVoximplant in a useeffect hook in a diffrent call Home.tsx
also i am passing navigation but stil its giving me this error can you please help me with this?

Home.tsx

```
import { initVoximplant } from '../../../utils/voximplant';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
        initVoximplant(navigation)
    }, [navigation])
```

voximplant.ts:

```
import { Voximplant } from 'react-native-voximplant';
import calls from './store';
import { VOXIMPLANT_APP, VOXIMPLANT_ACCOUNT } from '../Constants/voximplant';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export const initVoximplant = (navigation) => {
  const voximplant = Voximplant.getInstance();

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
      const e = await JSON.parse(userDataString!);
      const clientState = await voximplant.getClientState();

      if (clientState === Voximplant.ClientState.DISCONNECTED) {
        await voximplant.connect();
        await voximplant.login(
          `${e.user._id}@${VOXIMPLANT_APP}.${VOXIMPLANT_ACCOUNT}.voximplant.com`,
          e.user._id,
        );
      }
      if (clientState === Voximplant.ClientState.CONNECTED) {
        await voximplant.login(
          `${e.user._id}@${VOXIMPLANT_APP}.${VOXIMPLANT_ACCOUNT}.voximplant.com`,
          e.user._id,
        );
      }
      console.log(clientState)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error is je", e)
      let message = 'Unknown error. Try again';
      if (e.name === Voximplant.ClientEvents.ConnectionFailed) {
        message = 'Connection error, check your internet connection';
      }
    }
  };
  login();
  voximplant.on(Voximplant.ClientEvents.IncomingCall, (incomingCallEvent) => {
    calls.set(incomingCallEvent.call.callId, incomingCallEvent.call);
    navigation.navigate('IncomingCall', {
      callId: incomingCallEvent.call.callId,
    });
  });

  return function cleanup() {
    voximplant.off(Voximplant.ClientEvents.IncomingCall);
  };
};
```

Comment: what if you change your useEffect code to `if (navigation) initVoximplant(navigation);`